# Hugo /blog/list.html template not rendered

Tags: hugo

Is there any reason why mysite/blog/ list page doesn't use the blog/list.html layout given my directory structure? According to https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/unify-the-section-template-lookup-order-please-comment/5648 I should be able to.

Hugo version: v0.49/extended darwin/amd64 BuildDate: unknown

```
├── content
│   ├── _index.md
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── post-1.md
│   │   ├── post-2.md
│   │   ├── post-3.md
│   ├── get-started.md
│   └── services.md
├── data
├── layouts
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── _default
│   │   ├── baseof.html
│   │   ├── list.html -----> Don't want to use this layout
│   │   ├── taxonomy.html
│   │   └── terms.html
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── li.html
│   │   ├── list.html -----> Want to use this layout
│   │   ├── single.html
│   │   ├── summary-with-image.html
│   │   └── summary.html
│   ├── get-started
│   │   └── single.html
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── partials
│   │   ├── site-footer.html
│   │   ├── site-header.html
│   │   ├── site-scripts-footer.html
│   │   ├── site-scripts-head.html
```

Comment: Checking your file structure seems correct, unless you have conditions or errors on it.. do you have in any repo or anywhere I can check further?

Comment: You don't have a blog/list page. `blog/_index.md` will use the template `blog/list.html`.